# How to compare two object arrays and correct identical key values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I've searched, but haven't found precisely the trick I need.

I'm trying to compare 2 object arrays with the same keys, and update arr1 if the values in arr2 are different. [Here](https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/XWJOQGL) is a codepen to play with.

```
let arr1 = [{val1: "dog", val2: "friendly"},{val1: "cat", val2: "fluffy"}]

let arr2 = [{val1: "cat", val2: "evil"},{val1: "mouse", val2: "tiny"},{val1: "hippo", val2: "big"}]
```

Expected result of the function should be correcting the object including *val1:"cat"* in arr1:

```
 {val1: "cat", val2: "fluffy"} ----->  {val1: "cat", val2: "evil"}
```

and updated arr1 should return like this:

```
{val1: "dog", val2: "friendly"}, { val1: "cat", val2: "evil"}
```

Trick is, the code should also work both ways. So for example if there is {val1: "big", val2: "puma"} in arr1, it would change to {val1: "big", val2: "hippo"} by replacing "puma", since value "big" is linked to "hippo" in arr2.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.npmjs.com/package/extend?

Comment: Loop through `arr2` items. For each item, loop `arr1` for an item with the same `val1`, if found: set its value to the arr2 item's value. For larger arrays this has some overhead, so you might want to use a different structure for arr1 (like using `val1` as the key), which would make it a lot simpler I think.

Comment: @Philip as a beginner I'm a bit stumped on how the syntax should look like there. I'm thinking of maybe using forEach? But what exactly should be in the nested loop ? `arr2.forEach(function(obj) { .... })` trying to `console.log(obj.val1`) gave me an undefined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below function - this will satisfy in both way for arr1

```
function validateArray() {
        arr2.forEach(function(arr2Element) {
            arr1.forEach(function(arr1Element) {
                if (arr2Element.val1 === arr1Element.val1) {
                    arr1Element.val2 = arr2Element.val2;
                } else if (arr2Element.val2 === arr1Element.val1) {
                    arr1Element.val2 = arr2Element.val1;
                }
            });
        });
        console.log(arr1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through arr2 items. For each item, loop arr1 for an item with the same val1, if found: set its value to the arr2 item's value.

```js
let arr1 = [
    {
    val1: "dog",
    val2: "friendly"
  },
  {
    val1: "cat",
    val2: "fluffy"
  }
];

let arr2 = [{
  val1: "cat",
  val2: "evil"
},

{
  val1: "mouse",
  val2: "tiny"
},

{
  val1: "hippo",
  val2: "big"
}
];

function validate() {
  arr2.forEach(function(v2) {
     arr1.forEach(function(v, idx) {
      if (v2.val1 == v.val1) {
        console.log('Change', v.val2, 'to', v2.val2);
        arr1[idx].val2 = v2.val2;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<button id="validate" onclick="validate()">
Validate
</button>
```

For larger arrays this has some overhead, so you might want to use a different structure for arr1 (like using val1 as the key), which would make it a lot simpler I think.